# Deselect the rest of cells when first cell is select

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I have a tableview cells, and the titles I get from server. Titles are array of strings. The data is drawing like this

- All data
- List item
- Coffees
- Teas
- Dessert
- Main dishes

when I click on each of these I can easily select them and deselect, that part works perfect. Now i want that when i select List item, Coffees, teas, dessert, main dishes together, these 5 items will be deselected and all data(first cell) will be selected automatically.
I know i should write this in didselect method, only i dont know how to write logic correctly. Please help me to solve this. Thanks

this is my code example

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let isSelected = arrayOfTitles[indexPath.row].isSelected else {arrayOfTitles[indexPath.row].isSelected = true; return}
        arrayOfTitles[indexPath.row].isSelected = !isSelected
        filter?.values?[indexPath.row].isSelected = !isSelected
        for i in 1..<arrayOfTitles.count {
            if arrayOfTitles[i].isSelected == isSelected {
                arrayOfTitles[0].isSelected = isSelected
                arrayOfTitles[i].isSelected = !isSelected
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let isSelected = arrayOfTitles[indexPath.row].isSelected else {arrayOfTitles[indexPath.row].isSelected = true; return}
        arrayOfTitles[indexPath.row].isSelected = !isSelected
        filter?.values?[indexPath.row].isSelected = !isSelected
        let allSelected = arrayOfTitles[1...].filter { $0.isSelected }
        if allSelected.count == arrayOfTitles.count - 1 {
           arrayOfTitles[0].isSelected = true
            (1..<arrayOfTitles.count).forEach { arrayOfTitles[$0].isSelected = false }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the last line it comes error that says "Cannot assign to property: '$0' is immutable"

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So it works, but only after i select the 5 items and deselect them, after that the logic starts to work fine.But thanks for the idea, i have worked on this very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Because a table view maintains its own array of selected rows (`IndexPaths`), you don't really need to maintain a separate `.isSelected` property on your data. If you *need* it (for state persistence, for example), you can always grab the selected rows when needed.

So, here's another approach...

I'm guessing that if you have *some* of the rows selected, and you then **select the top row**, you would also want to deselect the other rows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var arrayOfTitles: [String] = [
        "All data",
        "List Item",
        "Coffees",
        "Teas",
        "Dessert",
        "Main dishes",
    ]
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayOfTitles.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath)
        c.textLabel?.text = arrayOfTitles[indexPath.row]
        return c
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // ignore if nothing is selected
        guard let paths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else { return }
        
        // if we selected the top row ("All data"), deselect the others
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            // deselect the other rows
            paths.forEach {
                if $0.row != 0 {
                    tableView.deselectRow(at: $0, animated: true)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // get the selected rows as a sorted array of Int
            let rows: [Int] = (paths.map { $0.row }).sorted()
            // Int array of rows 1 thru 5
            let myFiveRows: [Int] = Array(1...5)
            // if the two arrays are equal (they're both [1,2,3,4,5])
            if rows == myFiveRows {
                // deselect all
                tableView.selectRow(at: nil, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
                // select the top row
                tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
            }
        }
    }

}
```